# model.addrow() change background color

Tags: java, swing, colors, jtable

I have a table, in which I am adding new rows.  After 6 rows with data I want to add an empty row with the background color red then, another 6 rows with white background and so on.

```
private void populate(){

    DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel) table.getModel();
    int i,j;
    for(j=0;j<6;j++){

               for(i=0;i<6;i++){
                        model.addRow(new Object[]{"dada","dadaddd"});
               }

               model.addRow(new Object[]{"",""}); //<-this is the red row i want to add 
   }
}
```

How can I change the color of the empty row?

Comment: Take a look at [this](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2010/01/24/table-row-rendering/).

Comment: crossposted http://www.daniweb.com/software-development/java/threads/400748

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer , like mre told me

```
public Component prepareRenderer(
    TableCellRenderer renderer, int row, int column)
{
    Component c = super.prepareRenderer(renderer, row, column);

    //  add custom rendering here

    return c;
}
```